# Multiple Geth on same machine with different genesis

Tags: go-ethereum

i have been running multiple geth instances on a single machine for the conceptualization of private blockchain. Now i am trying to run two different and separate from each other geth instances on same machine but i am running into this error.

```
INFO [03-18|04:08:42.491] Blockchain manager stopped
INFO [03-18|04:08:42.547] Stopping Ethereum protocol
INFO [03-18|04:08:42.562] Ethereum protocol stopped
INFO [03-18|04:08:42.572] Transaction pool stopped
INFO [03-18|04:08:42.601] Database closed                          database=C:\\Production\\data\\geth\\chaindata
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: Access is denied.
```

Is it possible to achieve what i am trying to do? Two different geth instances and each one initialized with different genesis.json but on same machine. Commands i am using to run geth instances for this scenario.

Geth 1 Directory `c:/Project`

```
geth --datadir data --port 30311 --ws --wsport 8502 -wsapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --wsorigins="*" --networkid 786 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x042b1b16eccb6c6bafdceaafea5e9e117990feef' --password data/password.txt --mine console
```

Geth 2  Directory `c:/production`

```
 geth --datadir data --port 30312 --ws --wsport 8503 -wsapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --wsorigins="*" --networkid 123 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x6626ee38f917d1e922b86f3eb7e27ea1749b3242' --password data/password.txt --mine console
```

Comment: Try giving them different `--ipcpath` values, e.g. pass `--ipcpath geth-dev.ipc` to the first instance and `--ipcpath geth-prod.ipc` to the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from TCP ports, `geth` opens so-called local sockets on UNIX and named pipes on Windows.  While local sockets reside in data dirdctory, and setting different data directories is enough to avoid naming conflicts, named pipes share the same global namespace, so you need to explicitly set different pipe names for your `geth` instances via `--ipcpath` command line option, e.g. pass `--ipcpath geth-dev.ipc` to the first instance and `--ipcpath geth-prod.ipc` to the second one.